# npm install unhandled rejection

Tags: node.js, git, npm

I'm trying to figure out why `npm install` no longer works on a Ubuntu 14 LTS machine.

The project is a `nuxt` project, and `npm install` works on a Unix machine.

I have tried uninstalling and reinstall both node and npm.

Current versions are:

- node: v10.15.1
- npm : 6.4.1

If I run `npm install --verbose`

we get

```
Unhandled rejection Error: Command failed: /usr/bin/git clone --depth=1 -q -b master git://github.com/dcodeIO/long.js.git /home/<USER>/.npm/_cacache/tmp/git-clone-226d28b2
/home/<USER>/.npm/_cacache/tmp/git-clone-226d28b2/.git: Permission denied

    at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:294:12)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:189:13)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:970:16)
    at Socket.stream.socket.on (internal/child_process.js:389:11)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:189:13)
    at Pipe._handle.close (net.js:600:12)

npm timing npm Completed in 128572ms
npm ERR! cb() never called!

npm ERR! This is an error with npm itself. Please report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://npm.community>

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/<USER>/.npm/_logs/2019-02-21T15_22_07_078Z-debug.log
```

the last few lines of that file are:

```
17822 silly extract core-js@2.6.5 extracted to /home/<USER>/<PROJECT>/node_modules/.staging/core-js-49a396dc (950ms)
17823 silly extract vuetify@1.5.1 extracted to /home/<USER>/<PROJECT>/node_modules/.staging/vuetify-c586b9e6 (4197ms)
17824 timing npm Completed in 128572ms
17825 error cb() never called!
17826 error This is an error with npm itself. Please report this error at:
17827 error <https://npm.community>
```

Comment: Did you try clearing npm cache ?

Comment: @MebinJoe yes, even this npm@5+ warns that cache is self healing

Comment: Didyou try resetting the permissions of your `/Users/../.npm/` recursively to your user.

Details:* https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions
* https://docs.npmjs.com/troubleshooting/try-clearing-the-npm-cache

Comment: @MebinJoe was on some of those pages previously. uninstall and reinstalled. Now I have permission errors. running with `sudo ` results in same issue. 

please save me :(

Comment: That's what I was saying. Might be a permission issue for the user in your Ubuntu 14 LTS machine.

Answer (score 1):

try to install node by nvm (node version manager).

**curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.34.0/install.sh | bash**

just try these simple step's (hope its work in your case):

- copy and paste this command in the terminal after completing this.
- close and re-open the terminal
- type nvm to check is nvm installed on your system.
- type by checking **nvm ls** (this show you a default node installed version).
- then go to your project directory and use **npm install** or **npm i**